# Extracting multiple values from string

Tags: c#

I have the following strings variations:

```
OFFSET P-1D INTERSECT ~(T13)
OFFSET P-11H INTERSECT ~(T3)
OFFSET P8Y INTERSECT ~(M3)
```

and I need to parse out the values from the string in this format:

```
OFFSET P{val1}{val2} INTERSECT ~({val3}{val4})
```

for example:

```
OFFSET P{-11}{H} INTERSECT ~({T}{3})
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you need an effective algorithm to get these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions!

```
var rg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^OFFSET P(-?\d+)([DHY]) INTERSECT ~\(([TM])(\d+)\)$");

var match = rg.Match("OFFSET P-1D INTERSECT ~(T13)");

// match.Groups(1).Value = "-1"
// match.Groups(2).Value = "D"
// match.Groups(3).Value = "T"
// match.Groups(4).Value = "13"
```

In action: https://regex101.com/r/bA3dB6/1

Comment: Not only does this waste memory on matches it has the potential to take very long given or malformed enough or crafted input. Why not use split with a maximum and some other minimum verification?

Comment: I confess that what you say about my code is new to me. I'm familiar with the idea of bad backtracking but I don't see how it applies to this expression. What crafted input would take an excessive amount of time? How would you use split in this case?  (OK to take to chat if necessary.)

Comment: Regex is the fastest way to go.

Comment: @papapa can you back that up? I do agree that regex is well suited for this particular problem, and speed won't be an issue, but would regex really be faster than using a few `IndexOf`'s? I haven't tried, but you seem to be sure.

Comment: I was hoping that there will be something easier than regex, but it was just a fantasy.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis There is no such thing as "back it up" when talking about software performance. Every case needs to be benchmarked with a real life data input and this is the only way you can tell for sure.

Comment: If there is really a huge amount of input to be scanned, like in the hundreds of thousands of lines, then it might pay off to avoid regex. Otherwise I lean towards using a regex and living with it.

Comment: @papapa Ok so we shouldn't simply assume that "Regex is the fastest way to go" then.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Give it a try and tell us how it went.

Comment: @papapa Why would I try anything if you already said that Regex is the fastest way to go? All we need is _your_ benchmarks, so we know you've already measured it, instead of just writing something random.